# Django moving from Development server to Deployment Server

Tags: django, deployment, static

Regarding this documentation page from the Django website,

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/

where it says for development "With that said, Django does support static files during development. You can use the django.views.static.serve() view to serve media files."

So my question is, if I use this method, How much work is required to move to apache.

Currently I have a symbolic link to my image folder in the /var/www folder, and in the Django settings I have set the media url to :

```
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:80/Images/'
```

This seems like a fairly easy hack but my project is going to get very big (with lots of css, js and pdfs) and I doubt if this method is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was to have apache itself intercept the static files urls and serve them directly without invoking django at all. So my apache config looked something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myproject.com


    Alias /static /docs/my_website/static
    <Directory /docs/my_website/static>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /favicon.ico /docs/my_website/static/images/icons/favicon.ico

    Include "/13parsecs/conf/django.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can just keep doing whatever you're doing in the dev environment, and when you get to apache it won't invoke django at all for static content, which is what you want.

Comment: Interesting method. It's a more decoupled method, I like it. If I want to switch to another Web Server it would be easier too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly good way of doing things. The only change you'll need to make is to put the actual URL of your site, rather than the localhost IP.

Comment: Which method, the one I am currently using?

Answer (score -1):

Don't "move to Apache", start using it in the first place. None of the software needed has licensing fees and runs on almost any platform, so the **only** excuse you could have is "I'm too lazy".

Comment: Django is not a software, it is a framework. Neither license or platform has any relevance to this question, please read the question carefully. laziness is easily mistaken with efficiency ask any software developer.

Comment: HTTPd is a web server. mod_wsgi is a HTTPd module that provides a WSGI container. Read the answer carefully.

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain any of the strings HTTPd or mod_wsgi. Read your own comments carefully.

Comment: Yes I do. The point is, if you cannot answer a question don't make the attempt.